# Material not loaded in sdkdemo project or also there is no custom timeline

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Recently we have tried to implement your SDK demo in our project, But as per our result we followed every step you mentioned in this doc but there is no material coming from Huwai app gallery column also let us know how can we able to load assets from local

-- need to know the transition and animation pattern so that we can also build custom transitions for our application.

-- Custom timeline that is implemented on the UI SDK is not available on this Demo SDK, where is documentation on how can we implement it custom timeline in our application.

Comment: hi@oli ahmed, Can I confirm whether a real APIkey is set in your demo? like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Wia.png).

Answer (score 0):

> -- Custom timeline that is implemented on the UI SDK is not available on this Demo SDK, where is documentation on how can we implement it custom timeline in our application.

The UI SDK cannot be used to customize the timeline. You need to use video-editor-sdk. pls kindly refer to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Media-Guides/editing_project-0000001166551608?ha_source=hms1).